# Python | NumPy - Poor performance for algorithm that sums y values with same x value

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to develop an algorithm that sums every y values with the same x values. The following works fine for small datasets, but once the number of rows crosses into the tens of thousands the use of a for loop to sum over all of the unique x values is very slow. Is there another way to do this that does not involve iterating over every unique x value one value at a time?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 2], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 8], [3, 9]])
x= data[:,0]
x = np.unique(x)
y = []
for item in x:
            y.append(data[data[:,0] == item].sum())
    
plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the output is right for your algorithm, I ran the code and y turns out to be [13, 10, 27] and I'm not sure if that's the intended output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use pandas groupby to group the same values and then take the sum of those?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 2], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 8], [3, 9]])
x= data[:,0]
x = np.unique(x)
y = []
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.groupby(0).sum()
plt.plot(df.groupby(0).sum())
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Dataframe to improve performance (~182 times faster for 100K rows)

**Code**

```
def use_df(data):
    ' Method based upon Datarame manipulations '
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    # Duplicate column 0 since will group based upon it and want to include it in sum
    df['groups'] = df[0]

    # Pandas series with desired values
    return df.groupby(0, as_index=True).sum().sum(axis=1)

def use_op(data):
    ' Based upon original post '
    x= data[:,0]
    x = np.unique(x)
    y = []
    for item in x:
        y.append(data[data[:,0] == item].sum())
    return y
```

**Validation**

Check that two functions produce the same output.

```
 data = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 5], [2, 2], [2, 4], [3, 1], [3, 8], [3, 9]])
 print(use_df(data).tolist()==using_op(data))
 # Output: True (i.e. both produce values of  [13, 10, 27])
```

**Time**

*Timing using original data*

```
use_op   use_df
110 us   5.45 ms
```

*Time using simulated data*

```
Number Rows              use_op    use_df
1000                     5.18 ms   2.38 ms
10,000                   5.93 ms   53.5 ms
100,000                 14.6 ms    2.67 secs
```

*Timing code with simulated data*

```
def create_data(n):
    ' Create random numpy array dimension n x 2'
    k = n //10      # Value variation is 10% of the number of rows        
    data = np.random.randint(1, k+1, n)
    return np.reshape(data, (-1, 2))

for n in [1000, 10000, 100000]:
    print(n)
    data = create_data(n)
    %timeit use_df(data)
    %timeit use_op(data)
```

**Summary**

- Original method faster for small dataset
- DataFrame is ~9x faster with 10K rows and 182x faster with 100K rows.